# force editor to break line when writing html on the fly from code behind

Tags: html, editor

I am creating html on the fly from code behind and write it to file.

when open the file in visual studio I can see the html in one line.

Is there a way to force the editor to accept line break when creating the code on the fly?

what are those line break that we cause by pressing enter in the editor and how is the editor keeping them?

Answer (score 0):

ok find the answer

just insert `\r\n` where we want the line break